# What benefits do I get from learning Scheme?

Tags: programming-practices, self-improvement, scheme

I'm a java programmer and I've decided to learn a bit about theoretical computer science. I don't have a degree in that and a little background would help me a lot since I don't know anything other than coding when it comes to software development.

I've searched this website for answers and I've found a lot of people recommending the book "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" but since I don't have the required mathematical know-how to handle this book, I decided to go with "How to Design Programs" instead.

My question here is what would I gain from this experience? Would it teach me about Computer Science like I want? Or am I better off reading about algorithms and data structures instead?

Comment: Scheme? With related to what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an introductory CS text... there isn't a lot of math involved. I think you would be best served by *picking up* the math you need, and going with SICP. Maybe you can pick up what you need from Khan Academy. Part of the beauty of SICP is that it teaches you a mathematical way to *think* about problems, in a way that only a functional language can (IMO).

Comment: but how to design programs is supposed to be an enhancement to SICP,I guess,and they both server the same purpose

Comment: This definitely is not a math intensive text.